# desperate for NOOB instructions. No webcam or Microphone on Macbook pro with ubuntu installed

Tags: microphone, webcam, macbook-pro

I have Ubuntu 20.4 installed on a partition on my Mac. So far so good.
except for the internal Mic and camera are not working.
I have been trying to fix it by installing drivers, however the instructions I have found are already above my knowledge. When describing edit the modules and commands like "Make" I recieve return messages in the command line that what I have typed in incorrect, unrecgonised ect.

Can someone please help or point me to a step by step guide for someone who is really trying to learn Ubuntu what I need to do to get the webcam and Mic activated.

I finally decided I need to get off Mac Os and move to Ubuntu. The Mac Os is out-dating itself and becoming obsolete faster than I can afford. the webcam and Mic are crucial to this new adventure. please help!

Comment: Unfortunately there isn't enough information here to offer a *specific* solution. Could you [edit] your question to include: (0) which MacBook Pro you're using (1) the Terminal output of `sudo lsusb`. With this, it may be possible to point you to a solution that works, as the camera and audio are rather tricky devices to get working on some models.

Comment: Bus 002 Device 002: ID 05ac:8406 Apple, Inc. Card Reader
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 05ac:0273 Apple, Inc. Internal Keyboard/Trackpad (ISO)
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 05ac:8290 Apple, Inc. Bluetooth Host Controller
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

Comment: macbook pro 13inch 2015

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/1432776/925128

Answer (score 1):

Treat this as two problems: Camera and Microphone.
I can, given the lack of information in your question, (Read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting ) offer a possible solution.  What does `sudo lshw -short` tell you? Read `man lshw sudo`.

Many device access problems can be resolved through group membership changes.

Your `$device` is possibly `/dev/video*`.

Specifically, if `ls -l $device` shows that the group permissions (the second "`rwx`" triplet) is "`rw`" (e.g."`-rw-rw----`"), then, adding oneself to the group that owns the device will grant `rw` access.

Here's how:

```
# change to your device name 
device="/dev/dvdrw"
sudo adduser $USER $(stat -c "%G" $device)
```

This allows you membership in the group that can `rw` the device, **but there is one more step.**

To make all your processes members of the new group, logout and login. Group memberships are set up at `login` time.

To create a single process in the new group (for testing, prior to logout/login):

```
newgrp $(stat -c "%G" $device)
```

or, just type the group name. See `man newgrp`.

Comment: from your advice above,

Macbook pro 13inch 2015
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 05ac:8406 Apple, Inc. Card Reader
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 05ac:0273 Apple, Inc. Internal Keyboard/Trackpad (ISO)
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 05ac:8290 Apple, Inc. Bluetooth Host Controller
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

the problems
1) internal microphone not functioning 
2) Isight Camera not working 
3) Im new to this and hardly understand anything that you commented above, I do not know what "rw" means

Comment: Please [edit] your post to add new information, properly formatted. Information added via comments is hard for you to format, hard for us to read and ignored by future readers (who have better answers). Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our way to help you improve your question. All facts about your system and problem should go in the Question with [edit].  You may click on any of these [edit] links to [edit] your question.